# React-Virtualized or React-Window table with external scrollbar

Tags: react-virtualized

I need to create a virtualized table with an external scrollbar, something similar to what Discourse.org does on their [discussions](https://try.discourse.org/t/what-happens-when-a-topic-has-over-1000-replies/301/316):

[image: image of discourse.org]

React-Virtualized has a [WindowScroller](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/WindowScroller) that manages the window scroll to scroll through the list.

How can I do something similar but having the scroll in a custom element?

I'm also open to any solutions even they are not based on React-Virtualized and React-Window.

Answer (score 0):

The same WindowScroller component has a `scrollComponent` prop that would scroll in a parent component, but not `window`.